# Number of solutions for $x^2 \equiv x \pmod m$

Tags: congruences

What is the number of solutions of $x^2 \equiv x \pmod m$ for any positive integer $m$?

Comment: look at basic cases and guess the general solution, prove it then. note that you are looking at number that are equal to its square (of course modulo n!)

Comment: $x^2\equiv x$ implies $x^2-x=x(x-1)\equiv 0$. That should tell you that the factors of $m$ and whether any of them have multiples that are adjacent play a huge role in how many solutions there are.

Comment: @Arthur Could you please explain a bit more please?

Comment: @YogeshGhaturle I know you are new to the site, but you must understand that this page is not an "instant full solution" black box. This site is here to *help you learn*, not to solve everything for you. So when you get a helpful answer (like the one by Arthur), don't just say "can you explain a bit more". Instead, look at the answer, take a piece of paper and a pencil, and try to work from there on. And for a bit longer than 5 minutes. Then, if you are still stuck, explain what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: sad to see such a good question downvoted. i added my positive vote

Comment: One answer seems to be hinting that there are only 2 roots, notice that there are 4 roots (mod 6): 0,1,3 and 4

Comment: @djechlin, there is no complete answer in that thread

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias it's *the exact same question* though. If everyone in that thread was content posting hints you don't just keep asking the exact same question until you get an answer.

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias If you think that my answer is hinting that there are only two solutions, then you are wrong.

Comment: feel free to improve your answer

Comment: @djechlin It's _not_ the exact same question, since the other question is in a completely different context. Do you think throwing around words like "idempotent" and "ring" is going to help the OP in any way?

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias No, I think I have put down enough effort into my answer as it is. It doesn't need any correcting, and I don't want to post a _complete_ solution.

Comment: @Arthur sorry, you're right. It's 99% the same question. You have to delete the words "ring of" before "Z_n" and change the "n" to an "m." @ OP, idempotent means x^2 = x. @ Arthur Now the OP is qualified to read the question.

Comment: @djechlin Yes, now the questions are the same. That isn't too hard. But the answers are still given in the context of abstract algebra, not number theory. If you want to translate, for instance, the first answer and post it here, you are welcome to do so, but it would take considerable effort compared to how quickly you translated the question. Isomorphisms and direct products do not translate so well.

Comment: Might be the same question but 1) the other question is asked in abstract algebra terms which may be out of the OPs vocabulary and 2) They answers *this* question have come up with are *better*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is to count the roots of $x^2 - x \equiv 0 \pmod m$.

Exploring the problem for specific numbers of $m$ first, we see it can have:

- $2$ roots mod $2$: `0,1`
- $4$ roots mod $6 = 2\cdot 3$: `0,1,3,4`
- $8$ roots mod $30 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$: `0,1,6,10,15,16,21,25,30`
- $16$ roots mod $210 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$

A good guess is it has $2^r$ roots, for some $r$ depending on $m$.

With some more exploring you can notice that:

- There is $2$ roots modulo a prime power.
- There is $2^r$ roots, where $r$ is the number of prime factors of $m$.

---

A degree $d$ polynomial can only have at most $d$ roots mod some prime $p$. It can have more roots than its degree modulo prime powers though. We need to prove that this special polynomial has exactly $2$ roots mod each prime power $p^k$.

**Lemma** $x^2-x \equiv 0$ has $2$ roots $\pmod {p^k}$.

*proof*: Clearly $x=0$ and $x=1$ are roots, as you have pointed out. We just need to show now that if $z$ is a root then $z=0$ or $z=1$. To prove that we can split into two cases: When $z|p^k$ and when $z$ is coprime to $p^k$. The coprime case is easy because $z$ is zero or invertible.
For the case $z|p^k$: Put $z = p^h$ (with $h < k$) and consider $$p^{2h} - p^h \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}.$$ this is impossible of $2h \le k$ so suppose $2h > k$, we have $k < 2h < 2k$ and $p^{2h-k} \equiv p^k$ but this implies $2h-k = k$, so $2h = 2k$, but this contradicts $h < k$.

Secondly we can use the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to put together the $2$ roots mod each prime power of $m$ to get $2^r$ roots mod $m$.

**Lemma** If $a,b$ are coprime then if $P(x)$ has $m$ roots mod $a$ and $n$ roots mod $b$ then it has $mn$ roots mod $ab$.

*proof*: Label the roots mod $a$ as $\{r_i\}$ and the roots mod $b$ as $\{s_j\}$ then the roots mod $ab$ are $\{(r_i, s_j) \}$ of which there are $|\{r_i\}|\cdot|\{s_j\}| = nm$.

---

Putting these two lemmas together lets you conclude: There are $2^r$ roots, where $r$ is the number of prime factors of $m$.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment above, we have
$$
x^2 \equiv x \pmod m\\
x^2 - x \equiv 0 \pmod m\\
x(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod m
$$
What if $m$ was a prime $p$, how many solutions would the equation have? What if $m$ was the *power* $p^n$ of some prime? Here it pays off to think about divisibility and what being a prime means (hint: there are two solutions either way).

Now, for an $m$ that is *not* the power of a prime, then it can still be written as a product of such:
$$
m = p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}
$$
At this point, you have either heard about the Chinese remainder theorem or you haven't. If you have, you should know what to do at this point, especially since I just told you about it. Assuming that $p_i \neq p_j$ when $i \neq j$, you get $k$ different congruence relations, each with $2$ solutions, which means that the total number of solutions to the original problem is...?

If you haven't heard about it, then I suggest reading up on it. It is a very important result in number theory and you shouldn't be without it. You could start [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/crt.html), or use google, or if you have a favourite textbook, it's probably in there as well.

Comment: This is what i understood. Correct me if I am wrong. $x(x-1) \equiv 0  mod m $ can be written as two equations $x \equiv 0modm $ or $ x \equiv 1modm$. Now if m is prime or not doesn't matter there would only one solution for each equation .

Comment: @YogeshGhaturle So either $x \equiv 0$ or $x \equiv 1$. That looks like two solutions to me. But if $m$ is composite, then there might be _other_ solutions as well. For instance, in the case $m = 12$ you also have $x \equiv 4$ or $9$.

Comment: How to solve using CRT for composite m. I am not getting these solution if I try to solve for m=12. Could you tell how did you reach this solution. I know that guessing could give me the answer.

Comment: Not prime matters.  As x(x-1) = 0 = m mod m etc.  If m = jk for example then x = j; x-1 = k (if possible)  so if m = k(k+1)  i.e.  6, 12, 20, 30 etc you can have solutions 2,3; 4,5 etc.  Also as x(x-1) = 0 = km you could have (if possible x = km' and y = m/m'.  For example if m = 10 then 20 = 4\*5 so x =5 and x - 1 = 4 would be a solution.

Comment: nice solution / hints ! It helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

So we get $x(x-1) \equiv \mod m$ so $m|x(x-1)$.  If $m$ is prime then either $m|x$ and $x \equiv 0 \mod m$ or $m|x -1$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod m$.

But what if $m$ is not prime.  If $m = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ then as $x$ and $x-1$ are relatively prime (they have only a difference of 1) then each $p_i^{k_i}|x$ or divides $x -1$.

In other words we need to find $x \equiv 0 \mod k$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod (j)$ where $m = j*k$ and $\gcd(j,k) = 1$ (Note if $m = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ there will by $2^i$ such sets of equations).  According to the chinese remainder theorem there will be one solution to each set of problems. (So $2^i$ solutions total).

### Example 1

Solve $x^2 = x \mod 12 \iff x(x-1) \equiv 0 \mod m$.  $12 = 3 \times 4$ so there will be the following solutions:

A) $x \equiv 0 \mod 12$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod 1$ which has one solution. via CRT.

B) $x \equiv 0 \mod 1$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod 12$ which has one solution.via CRT.

C) $x \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$ which has one solution.via CRT.

D) $x \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$ which has one solution. via CRT.

The solution to A) is $x= 0$, B) is $x =1$, C) $x = 9$ D)$ x = 4$

### Example 2

Solve $\ x^2 = x \mod 360$.
$360 \equiv 8 \times 9 \times 5$ so there will be 8 solutions:

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 360) \rightarrow x = 0$

$ (x \equiv 1 \mod 360) \rightarrow x = 1$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 8) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1\mod 45) \rightarrow x = 136$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 45) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1 \mod 8) \rightarrow x = 225$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 9) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1 \mod 40) \rightarrow x = 81$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 40) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1 \mod 9) \rightarrow x = 280$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 5) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1 \mod 72) \rightarrow x = 145$

$ (x \equiv 0 \mod 72) \  AND \ \  (x \equiv 1 \mod 5) \rightarrow x = 216$.

Which would have been practically impossible by trial and error.