# How to solve this quadratic congruence $x^2\equiv x\pmod{\!1000}$ and find self-reproducing numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, recreational-mathematics

A number $n$ is self-reproducing if the decimal digits of $n$ appear at the tail end of $n^{2}$ (in the same order); for example, $76$ is self-reproducing, since $76^{2}=5776$. Use congruences to find the two self-reproducing numbers $n$ such that $100<n<999$.

Here's the solution:

We see numbers $n$ such that $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {1000}$.
Thus, $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {8}$, giving $n\equiv 0, 1\pmod {8}$.
Also, $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {125}$, so $125\mid n(n-1)$, so $n\equiv 0, 1\pmod {125}$.
The numbers $n$ between $100$ and $999$ with $n=0, 1\pmod {125}$ are $125, 126, 250, 251, 375, 376, 500, 501, 625, 626, 750, 751, 875, 876$. Of these, the only $n\equiv 0, 1\pmod {8}$ are $376$ and $625$.

Above is the complete solution for this problem. But I do not understand, where/how did the $1000$ come from at first in $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {1000}$? I can observe that $1000=2^{3}\cdot 5^{3}$ by the prime factorization and that's why we considered two cases of both $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {8}$ and $n^{2}\equiv n\pmod {125}$ but I also do not understand how to get the solutions of $n\equiv 0, 1\pmod {8}$ and $n\equiv 0, 1\pmod {125}$. Can anyone please explain about these?

Comment: The number $b$ given by the last three digits of a number $a$ is exactly the remainder of the division of $a$ by $1000$, that's where the $1000$ comes from.

Comment: For the next part we can use the first lemma [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1661780/1096797).

Comment: Duplicate of  [Find all roots of $\,x^2\!\equiv x\pmod{\!900}$, i.e all idempotents in $\Bbb Z_{900}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902012/find-all-roots-of-x2-equiv-x-pmod-900-i-e-all-idempotents-in-bbb-z). The same methods work here.  Please don't post more duplicate answers below.

Comment: If you know Chinese Remainder Theorem, then everything becomes obvious. If $n$ is any integer whose prime factorization is $$n=p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$$ then any equation mod $n$ is uniquely determined by a system of equations mod $p_i^{a_i}$. In our case, an equation mod $1000$ is the same as a system of two equations mod $2^3$ and mod $5^3$, because $$1000=2^3 \cdot 5^3$$

Comment: @Crostul This is already explained in detail in the linked dupe.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you guys. I really appreciate it.